# Delete records with expiry date below current date in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks

When I click on save button, it collects the task details(name, message, the lapse period), and then it calculates the expiry date from the current date it was posted.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $currentDate = date("m-d-Y H:i:s");
    $currentDate_timestamp = strtotime($currentDate);
    $endDate_months = strtotime($request->lapse_period, $currentDate_timestamp);
    $packageEndDate = date("m-d-Y H:i:s", $endDate_months);

    echo " <br> " . $packageEndDate . " <br> ";

    Task::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'message' => $request->message,
        'lapse_period' => $request->lapse_period,
        'expires_at' => $packageEndDate
    ]);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

That works, and the question is: How can I create a task that runs every minute and deletes all records that expiry date lesser than the current date?

This is what I tried in the Kernel but nothing happens after a minute:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        $currentDate = date("m-d-Y H:i:s");
        $tasks = Task::all();
        foreach ($tasks as $task) {
            if($date->expires_at < $currentDate) {
                $task->delete();
            }
        }
    })->everyMinute();
}
```

Comment: for compare `date` use transform at `carbon` and try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
     $schedule->call(function () {
         Task::where('expires_at','<', Carbon::now())->delete();
     })->everyMinute();
}
```

Comment: Do I have to do something else after changing the kernel, cause nothing works. The records are still in my phpmyadmin and it as passed a minute

Comment: have you not added * * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
to your crontab?

Comment: I ran the command like this:php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1 to
That because I was already in my project folder. Is it wrong?

Comment: have you added the command to your crontab? because if it is being run through your crontab, it won't know where you are located.

Comment: add ->sendOutputTo(storage_path('taskoutput.txt')); to the end of your schedule after ->everyMinute and post the output (in storage/taskoutput.txt)  please.

Comment: Like this: })->everyMinute()->sendOutputTo(storage_path('taskoutput.txt'));?

Comment: yes, add that to the command and post the contents of the taskoutput.txt please.

Comment: I added but cant see the file in my storage folder

Comment: I just removed the Date from the Where clause and it works

Comment: @pseudoanime you can leave that `each->` out. Should still work and save you some time!

Comment: @deSousa, I'll update the anser, so that other people can find it in future

Comment: @pseudoanime Fair enough. 
I noticed that I have to run this command all the time when I make a request:
php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
Is there a way to make it run as long as the server is running?

Comment: @deSousa, add it to your cron job as per my instruction above. or set it up in your task scheduler (if you're using windows)

Comment: Sorry this is my very first time using this and I have no idea where to go. Meaning I dont know where to find "cron job" or how to set up "task schedular". Hope you do not mind guiding

Comment: what's your dev environment? windows or linux?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
  $schedule->call(function () {
    $currentDate = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $tasks = Task::all();
    foreach ($tasks as $task) {
     $dateTask = new \Carbon\Carbon($task->expires_at);
        if($dateTask < $currentDate) {
            $task->delete();
        }
    }
  })->everyMinute();
}
```

Comment: I added this more than 2 minutes ago but still nothing happens when I refresh my phpmyadmin

Comment: check you date bro and try

Comment: I even tried this: Task::whereDate('expires_at', '<', now() )->delete(); but does not work either

Comment: or change `\Carbon\Carbon::now()` for `\Carbon\Carbon::today()`